# Split a Spring Integration application into sub projects

Tags: spring, spring-integration

What is a correct way of splitting a Spring Integration project into sub projects (libraries)?

Like for example, I have a InboundChannelAdapter that receive files from FTP, a splitter that split by lines and a transformer that transform the data that I want to extract into a library and keep the rest of my flow in the main project. I don't know how I'll be able to define the output channel of the transformer from the main project and also how I'll be able from the main project to run multiple thread of this process in parallel.

The main objective of splitting the project into sub projects is to be able to reuse the sub projects later into Spring Cloud Stream applications.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are already familiar with  Spring Cloud Stream , you don't need to know anything else. That is only a way to split your monolith to the Message Driven Microservices using Spring Cloud Stream Binder foundation as a middleware to connect `input/output` channels between sub-projects.

Your main project can do the same. Define `@EnableBinding` and produce/receive messages over Binder through the same `input/output` channels model.

Comment: Isn't Spring Cloud Stream require either Kafka or Rabbit MQ? We don't have access to those for now.

Comment: Well, since you would like to have independent sub-project s, which obviously can be run on separate JVMs, there is no so much choice unless messaging middleware. So, that shouldn't be a big deal to follow already with the Spring Cloud Stream standard.

Comment: Using them as independent applications with a messaging middleware is the long term objective but right now we need to be able to separate everything into libraries that can either be used to create independent cloud applications (for the future) or to be used into a single web application without any messaging system (for now).

Comment: Ok. That's fine too. Only you need is correct Spring context configuration, to inject and configure objects from those libs as beans. In the end that should transparent for the target application: are those classes from a single jar or from several in the class path. I'd make `@Configuration` classes there and use `@Import` on the main `@Configuration` or just use Spring Boot with an appropriate `@ComponentScan`

Comment: I know about >@Configuration and >@Import but it doesn't allow me to expose options like setting the output channel to use.

Comment: Your question isn't clear. Any channel is a bean anyway. So, what you need just provide a correct injection or just use proper bean names for `inputChannel` and `outputChannel` options on the endpoint.

Comment: Thanks, I get it know. Sorry, I'm new to Spring Integration I didn't though about it this way.